# Green LED never lights up

Tags: led, boot-issues, pi-3

When I power up my Raspberry Pi 3, the red LED lights up and stays red until I unplug it. The green LED always stays off no matter what:
- I tried 3 different 2A chargers
- I tried 2 different SD cards (each formatted by the SD Formatter tool), both with NOOBS and Raspbian images copied on it (and also without any SD card)

Devices I try to plug on the Pi never get powered (and neither does the network)

Any idea on how to diagnose that Pi to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Who are the chargers and SD cards made by?

Comment: And the HDMI out doesn't display anything?

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? If so, check the voltages on the board when it's powered and make sure that it reads ~4.80-5.10 volts or so. The micro-SD slot is a good ground connection. Make sure you don't short out paths and pins with the other probe.

Comment: SD Cards were Kingston/Samsung ones, HDMI was always "silent" and no multimeter sadly. After contacting the retailer, they're exchanging it, so at least I'll know with a new Pi if it was anything I did or just bad luck to get a non-functional card.

Comment: After switching the Pi for a new one it turns out that I just had bad luck with my first one and everything was fine on the new one the way I was doing it